# How solve NoClassDefFoundError on unit test using new test support on Android Studio 1.1

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Using **Android Studio Beta 4** with the new android build plugin `1.1.0-rc`

I make some test under `src/test` and if no dependencies with Android framework work fine, but just a simple `Log.d()` or `Uri.parse` throw a `NoClassDefFoundError`

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `./gradlew test` from the terminal then running your tests in Android Studio again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue, i need to add those lines to my `build.gradle`

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```